# Symbol Not Found when Outputting Vector

Tags: c++

When trying to output an element of a vector, I get symbol not found errors for operator <<. Here is my code:

```
string sortline (string line)
{
    int position1 = 0;
    int position2 = 0;
    vector<string> vectorOfWords[100];
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    position1 = line.find("</span>", position2+1);
    position2 = line.find("</span>", position1+1);
    vectorOfWords[i] = line.substr(position1, position2);
    cout<<vectorOfWords[i]<<endl;
}
return "0";
}
```

I apologize for the lack of detail, but I'm not sure what other details to give. Please let me know if I'm missing something.
  Thank you very much!

Comment: you are creating 100 vectors and not 1 vector of size 100. try `vector<string> vectorOfWords(100);`

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: @MonadNewb why would he need to, am I making incorrect assumptions in my answer?

Comment: @aaronman I only read the question, not your answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vector<string> vectorOfWords(100);`

What you are curenttly doing is creating an array of 100 vector`s which I'm assuming is not what you want.

An array is created like this in c++

`int apples [50];`

So you can see why your code isn't working `<<` isn't defined for a whole vector which is what you are trying to print.

Comment: @UnsolvedCypher no prob, on this site generally you accept the answer if it solved your problem